# .NET Garbage Collector in a separate Thread?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage

Is it possible to run the garbage collection in a separate thread? So that it dosent block the main Thread of the process?

Comment: i think not. what is your specific problem? i never had performance problems with the GC

Comment: Iam using the Unity 3D engine and just opened up an empty project and let it run in the profiler. Even in an empty project iam getting HUGE performance spikes every time a full garbage collection happens.

Comment: It already works that way, the background GC runs on another thread.  That's why you see 8 msec spikes instead of 200+ msec spikes.  You really need to stop trying to solve a problem you don't have.  Or can't solve.

Comment: the you probably should read this, right? http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingAutomaticMemoryManagement.html

Comment: @Hans Passant It is a very very big problem. A realtime applications's performance is only as good as it's highest lagg spike.

Comment: .NET wouldnt be my choice for mealtime applications, its not deterministic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background GC happens on a separate thread already - that's why it's "background" - but there is part of the GC lifecycle that must block all threads in the process (not just the main thread) to complete - it's an unavoidable necessity that MS has worked to minimize - you can facilitate it in your code by being as smart with your own object lifecycles, using look aside lists instead of large amounts of new/disposes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, however there are some configurations where you can run it in the background automagically.

see this article on the [Garbage Collection process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx) .
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any ideas how i could use that in Unity?

Comment: I have not used Unity, so I do not have any experience.
I briefly read the article but it appears that it is the runtime configuration file in a .NET application that configures this.  So maybe this will point in the right direction >
You can use the <gcServer> element of the runtime configuration schema