# C# application CPU performance drastically slows down when program creates a high number of objects

Tags: c#, performance

I meet this weird performance issue:

1. I have a C# application which creates millions of C# objects.
2. In an unrelated part of the code, the application does a specific work which does not depend on the data allocated at step 1.

The CPU times seem to be correlated to the number of objects created at step 1.

I wrote a simple C# case which reproduces my issue.
`slowdown` command is called with the number of millions of string objects created before the `DoMyWork()` method is called.
As you can see, the same `DoMyWork()` method can take up to 3s if 200M of strings are instantiated.

- **Do I miss something in the language ?**
- **Suppose the physical memory limit is not reached, is there a max number of objects that should not be reached otherwise CLR would slow down ?**

I ran my test under Windows 10 on Intel Core i7-6700 and my program is a console release built in 32 bits mode (VS 2017 - fw 4.6.1):

```
slowdown 0
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 2 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 4 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 15 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 2 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 5 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 5 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 2 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 18 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 10 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 19 ms
```

slowdown 0 uses ~30M

```
slowdown 200
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 392 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 1120 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 3067 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 2 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 31 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 418 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 15 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 2 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 18 ms
Allocating 40000 hashtables: 416 ms
```

slowdown 200 uses ~800M

---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;

namespace SlowDown
{
  class Program
  {
    static string[] arr;

    static void CreateHugeStringArray(long size)
    {
      arr = new string[size * 1000000];
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) arr[i] = "";
    }


    static void DoMyWork()
    {
      int n = 40000;
      Console.Write("Allocating " + n + " hashtables: ");
      Hashtable[] aht = new Hashtable[n];

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        aht[i] = new Hashtable();
      }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      if (0 == args.Length) return;
      CreateHugeStringArray(Convert.ToInt64(args[0]));

      for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
      {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        DoMyWork();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.Write(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms\n");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your example, you don't create "millions of C# objects". You create a huge array of strings, and each array element will actually point to the same string object (see string interning).

Comment: How it perform if you try adding an integer to integer inside `DoMyWork`, since there is a boxing operation involved in the existing logic. Also you may consider using `StringBuilder` while repeatedly manipulating same string.

Comment: Add `GC.Collect()` right after `CreateHugeStringArray` and see if you still get the same times.

Comment: A very large string array is not analogous to millions of 'normal' C# objects. This is because a string array requires contiguous memory to be available (while millions of 'normal' C# objects do not). Also, 'normal' objects will be handled by the standard generational GC - while a large array will go into the Large Object Heap (which is GCed less aggressively).

Comment: dymanoid, the sample array points to different strings not the same one

Comment: @guista, have you seen the IL code for your loop? Do it, and you'll be surprised.

Comment: What does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory(v=vs.110).aspx (passing false) return prior to `Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();`? Are you running `Debug` or `Release` build?

Comment: @mjwills, I have been unable to find any evidence to support the "string array requires contiguous memory" statement. Can you point me in the right direction? The fact that each individual string (being an array of `char` struct values) requires contiguous storage makes total sense to me, but this does not necessarily translate to `string[]` requiring contiguous storage - at least not in theory.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy: all arrays are contiguous. A `string[]` is a contiguous sequence of `string` references. Of course, those `string` instances (if they are unique) need not all be allocated after each other; in that sense it's not contiguous.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379570(v=vs.80).aspx states `Probably the most common and well-known data structure is the array, which contains a contiguous collection of data items that can be accessed by an ordinal index.`

Comment: @mjwills, nevermind, it finally dawned on me that when you were talking about "millions of 'normal' C# objects" you were meaning "loose" objects tracked by GC as opposed to stored in a single large array. I initially interpreted your comment as implying that `string[]` storage semantics are different to `object[]`. My apologies regarding the confusion.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: thank you, it makes me understand better. Collecting the data immediately removed the issue and times are now around 30 ms. Unfortunately, I have to keep the huge data allocated (the real app requests the data in a huge referential). I corrected the sample using a static ref to keep the huge data alive so it matches my problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely Garbage Collector nasty stuff, which can freeze you main thread, even if it works mostly on a background thread, as mentionned here : [Garbage Collector Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639298/net-garbage-collector-in-a-separate-thread)

If you collect it, the time remains (in my case) around 90ms regardless of the size of the "unrelated" array.

Comment: In facts, in the real case, my application is loading a huge amount of data that is used later so it must not be collected. I updated my post by adding a case 2 where the data reference is kept in a static ref. Doing so, the array never get collected. However, execution performance is twice worse whereas GC should not do anything with the data. This makes me think that the slow down problem occurs when the whole data keeps allocated. The GC thread may watch all the active objects which decrease global application performance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the Garbage Collector running at the same time as your `DoMyWork`. The sheer size of the array it needs to clean up 'interrupts' the real work.

To see the impact of the GC, add these lines before your `StartNew` call - so that the GC work occurs **prior** to the timing:

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: I have just modified the code so the arr is a static field of the class, so once created by CreateHugeStringArray it is not going to be collected - and then put the DoMyWork section into a for loop. First time through the for loop is typically 350ms, all other times through the loop are about 50ms - any thoughts of the extra time required in that case.

Comment: It is likely the JIT @PaulF.

Comment: Should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates 10000 new string objects, forcing the garbage collection to run:

```
 string str = "";

 for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) str += i;
```

The performance of the garbage collector is proportional to

- The number of objects which have been allocated
- The total amount of memory in use

Your CreateHugeStringArray() allocates very large objects, increasing the total amount of memory in use. In extreme cases parts of this memory may be on disk (paged out) further slowing down the system.

The moral of your story is - don't allocate memory unless you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Did not find the reason yet, but is seems that having a huge array in LOH slows down garbage collection significantly. 
However, if we create many smaller arrays to hold the same amount of data (which goes to Generation 2 instead of LOH), GC does not slow so much. It seems that array with 1kk string pointers occupies about 4 million bytes of memory. So in order to avoid getting to LOH, the array must occupy less than 85 kilobytes. This is about 50 times lesser. You may use old trick to split big array into many small arrays

```
    private static string[][] arrayTwoDimentional;

    private static int _arrayLength = 1000000;

    private static int _sizeFromExample = 200;

    static void CreateHugeStringArrayTwoDimentional()
    {
        // Make 50 times more smaller arrays
        arrayTwoDimentional = new string[_sizeFromExample * 50][];

        for (long i = 0; i < arrayTwoDimentional.Length; i++)
        {
            // Make array smaller 50 times
            arrayTwoDimentional[i] = new string[_arrayLength / 50];
            for (var index = 0; index < arrayTwoDimentional[i].Length; index++)
            {
                arrayTwoDimentional[i][index] = "";
            }
        }
    }

    static string GetByIndex(long index)
    {
        var arrayLenght = _arrayLength / 50;
        var firstIndex = index / arrayLenght;
        var secondIndex = index % arrayLenght;

        return arrayTwoDimentional[firstIndex][secondIndex];
    }
```

Proof that GC is bottleneck here

[image: Inside DoMyWork]
After replacing array layout

[image: After moving]

In the example, array sizes are hard coded. There is a good example on Codeproject how you can calculate the size of type stored object, which will help to adjust the size of arrays:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129541/NET-memory-problem-with-uncontrolled-LOH-size-and